# How to differentiate between “no child rows exist” and “no parent row exists” in one SELECT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table C that references rows from tables A and B:

`id, a_id, b_id, ...`

and a simple query:

`SELECT * FROM C WHERE a_id=X AND b_id=Y`

I would like to differentiate between the following cases:

- No row exists in A where id = X
- No row exists in B where id = Y
- Both such rows in A and B exist, but no rows in C exist where a_id = X and b_id = Y

The above query will return empty result in all those cases.

In case of one parent table I could do a `LEFT JOIN` like:

`SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN C ON a.id = c.a_id WHERE c.a_id = X`

and then check if the result is empty (no row in A exists), has one row with NULL `c.id` (row in A exists, but no rows in C exist) or 1+ rows with non-NULL `c.id` (row in A exists and at least one row in C exists). A bit messy but it works, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this, especially if there is more than one parent table?

For example:

C is "things owned by people", A is "people", B is "types of things". When someone asks "give me a list of games owned by Bill", and there are no such records in C, I would like to return an empty list only if both "Bill" and "games" exist in their corresponding tables, but an error code if either of them doesn't.

So if there are no records matching "Bill" and "games" in table C, I would like to say "I don't know who Bill is" instead of "Bill has no games" if I don't have a record about Bill in table A.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  How would you have an `a_id` value in `C` that doesn't have a matching value in `A`.  Have you declared proper foreign key constraints?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM C WHERE a_id=X AND b_id=Y` gives you all rows where both IDs match. In case there is no such match you want to select `SELECT * FROM C WHERE a_id=X OR b_id=Y` instead? Or what else?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff it looks like what he is after is an integrity checker like some IBM installers incorporate, to validate that he data model is "good" before making changes to the underlying database.

Comment: @Ivan Poliakov use a full outer join

Comment: Please add sample data, it will make it a lot easier to understand your description

Comment: @pojo-guy Actually I just want to be able to return an error code instead of an empty list in case one of the parent keys is not valid, I've added an example to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to get a satisfactory solution using the following two features:

- Subselect bound to a column, which allows me to check if a row exists and (importantly) get a NULL value otherwise (e.g. `SELECT (SELECT id FROM a WHERE id = 1) as a_id)`)
- [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html)

Initial data:

```
CREATE TABLE people 
(
  id integer not null primary key, 
  name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE thing_types 
(
  id integer not null primary key, 
  name text not null
);

CREATE TABLE things
(
  id integer not null primary key, 
  person_id integer not null references people(id), 
  thing_type_id integer not null references thing_types(id), 
  name text not null
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'Bill');
INSERT INTO thing_types VALUES (1, 'game');

INSERT INTO things VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Duke Nukem');
INSERT INTO things VALUES (2, 1, 1, 'Warcraft 2');
```

And the query:

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT (SELECT id FROM people WHERE id=<person_id_param>) AS person_id, 
         (SELECT id FROM thing_types WHERE id=<thing_type_param>) AS thing_type_id
)
SELECT v.person_id, v.thing_type_id, things.name 
FROM 
  v LEFT JOIN things 
    ON v.person_id = things.person_id AND v.thing_type_id = things.thing_type_id
```

This query will always return at least one row, and I just need to check which, if any, of the three columns of the first row are NULLs.

In case if both parent table ids are valid and there are some records, none of them will be NULL:

```
person_id  thing_type_id  name
-------------------------------------
        1              1   Duke Nukem
        1              1   Warcraft 2
```

If either `person_id` or `thing_type_id` are invalid, I get one row where `name` is NULL and either `person_id` or `thing_type_id` is NULL:

```
person_id  thing_type_id  name
-------------------------------------
     NULL              1         NULL
```

If both `person_id` and `thing_type_id` are valid but there are no records in `things`, I get one row where both `person_id` and `thing_type_id` are not NULL, but the `name` is NULL:

```
person_id  thing_type_id  name
-------------------------------------
        1              1         NULL
```

Since I have a `NOT NULL` constraint on `things.name`, I know that this case can only mean that there are no matching records in `things`. If NULLs were allowed in `things.name`, I could include `things.id` instead and check that for NULLness.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table a(a_id integer not null primary key);
create table b(b_id integer not null primary key);

create table c(a_id integer not null references a(a_id)
        , b_id integer not null references b(b_id)
        , primary key (a_id,b_id)
        );

insert into a(a_id) values(0),(2),(4),(6);
insert into b(b_id) values(0),(3),(6);
insert into c(a_id,b_id) values(6,6);

PREPARE omg(integer,integer) AS
SELECT    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM a where a.a_id = $1) AS a_exists
        , EXISTS(SELECT * FROM b where b.b_id = $2) AS b_exists
        , EXISTS(SELECT * FROM c where c.a_id = $1 and c.b_id = $2) AS c_exists
        ;
EXECUTE omg(1,1);
EXECUTE omg(2,1);
EXECUTE omg(1,3);
EXECUTE omg(6,6);
```

-- with optional payload:

```
PREPARE omg2(integer,integer) AS
SELECT val.a_id AS va_id
        , val.b_id AS vb_id
        , EXISTS(SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.a_id = $1) AS a_exists
        , EXISTS(SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.b_id = $2) AS b_exists
        , EXISTS(select * FROM c WHERE c.ca_id = val.a_id AND c.cb_id = val.b_id ) AS c_exists
        , a.*
        , b.*
        , c.*
FROM (values ($1,$2)) val(a_id,b_id)
LEFT JOIN a ON a.a_id = val.a_id
LEFT JOIN b ON b.b_id = val.b_id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.ca_id = val.a_id AND c.cb_id = val.b_id
        ;
EXECUTE omg2(1,1);
EXECUTE omg2(2,1);
EXECUTE omg2(1,3);
EXECUTE omg2(6,6);
```

Comment: But I still need to return the actual data if it exists :)

Comment: I like your solution; I managed to get away with a single join using CTE (see below).

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 cases, the third one is a bit more complex but can be achieved by using cross join between a and b, all three cases in a union could be like this

```
select a_id, b_id , 'case 1' from c 
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.a_id=c.a_id)

union all 

select a_id, b_id ,'case 2' from c 
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.b_id=c.b_id)

union all 

select a_id, b_id, 'case 3' from a cross join b
where exists (select 1 from c where c.a_id=a.a_id)
and exists (select 1 from c where c.b_id=b.b_id)
and not exists (select 1 from c where c.b_id=b.b_id and c.a_id=a.a_id)
```